# SSIS fails to create a package programmatically: No description found

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Out of ideas and about to start pulling my hair out. Maybe someone out there can help:

I'm getting the following error when I try to create an SSIS package from C#:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException:
>   No description found --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   No description found    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnections100.Add(String
>   bstrConnectionType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Connections.Add(String
>   connectionType)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Connections.Add(String
>   connectionType)    at
>   RSL.Service.FileProcessing.BusinessLogic.PackageGeneration.ExcelConnectionTypeProvider.AddConnectionManager(Package
>   package)    at
>   RSL.Service.FileProcessing.BusinessLogic.PackageGeneration.PackageGenerator.ConstructPackage(Boolean
>   createNew, String password)    at
>   RSL.Service.FileProcessing.BusinessLogic.PackageGeneration.PartnerSubschemaPackageGenerator.GeneratePackage(Collection`1
>   errors)    at
>   RSL.Service.FileProcessing.BusinessLogic.SsisManager.CreatePackage(PartnerSubSchema
>   partnerSubSchema, Int32&amp;
>   ssisPackageDocumentId, Collection`1
>   errors)    at
>   RSL.Service.FileProcessing.Implementation.FileProcessingService.CreatePackage(BaseRequest`1
>   request)    at
>   SyncInvokeCreatePackage(Object ,
>   Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs,
>   Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The thing is, the code works perfectly on 3 other environments, which indicates a configuration problem, so won't post the code for now, though it's based on the Package Generation Sample [here](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/)

The box I'm deploying on is running:
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) with all shared components (running without any issues as far as I can tell)
- Access Database Engine for Office 2007

As far as I can tell, the only difference between this box and all the others is the OS: Vista on my dev box, and Windows Server 2008 Standard (Build 6002) on the 2 other test boxes...

It's really infuriating... since the SSIS creation package is being done by a service running on IIS7, I've made sure that the necessary accounts have write access to the folder where the SSIS package is saved.

Also, [a search on the internet](http://www.google.co.za/search?hl=en&q=no+description+found&meta=) reveals that this error can get thrown in SQL Server 2005 but it's in the context of maintenance plans and Visio 2003, which are not applicable here...

If anyone has any clue or suggestion, I'd greatly appreciate it. For the time being, I'll continue banging my head against this brick wall :)

---

UPDATE: The app can also generate packages using Flat File Sources, and that also falls through, indicating this isn't an Excel specific problem, but an SSIS problem?

UPDATE 2: Another thing that might be of significance is that this box is a VMWare virtual machine, all the others are physical servers...

Comment: @SQLMenace: nope. only my dev machine is 32 bit, all the others are 64. but since I'm using the Office 2007 data components, the IIS7 worker processes are running in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone, the problem seemed to be caused when requests to the WCF service which generates the package were secured using an AD STS and the binding was ws2007FederationHttpBinding. When changed to basicHttpBinging with no authentication, the package was generated successfully. I have no knowledge of WIF to speak of, and I had a lot of help with this from someone who does, so that's about all I can share :)